# Summing duplicate values while reading in data for different types of outputs

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter

I am reading in 5000 rows of data from a `stream` as follows from top to bottom and store it in a new CSV file.

```
ProductCode |Name   | Type  | Size | Price
ABC | Shoe  | Trainers  | 3 | 3.99
ABC | Shoe  | Trainers  | 3 | 4.99
ABC | Shoe  | Trainers  | 4 | 5.99 
ABC | Shoe  | Heels | 4 | 3.99
ABC | Shoe  | Heels | 5 | 4.99
ABC | Shoe  | Heels | 3 | 5.99
...
```

Instead of having duplicate entries, I want the CSV to have one row but with the Price summed:
E.g. If I want a csv file with only ProductCode, Name and Type, ignoring the Size. I want it too look like this:

```
ProductCode |Name   | Type  | Price
ABC | Shoe  | Trainers  | 14.97
ABC | Shoe  | Heels | 14.97
```

Show only ProductCode, Name:

```
ProductCode |Name   | Price
ABC | Shoe  | 29.94
```

Show ProductCode, Name, Size, ignoring Type:

```
ProductCode |Name   | Type  | Size | Price
ABC | Shoe  | 3 | 14.97
ABC | Shoe  | 4 | 9.98
ABC | Shoe  | 5 | 4.99
```

I store each row with all fields as a `Product` and keep a list of all `Product`s:

```
public class Product
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

And then output the needed fields into the csv depending on the `csvOutputType` using `ConvertToOutputFormat` which is different for each Parser.

```
public class CodeNameParser : Parser {
    public override string ConvertToOutputFormat(Product p) {
         return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", p.ProductCode, p.ProductName, p.Price);
    }
}
```

My code is then:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(directory, string.Format("{0}.csv", name));            
switch (csvOutputType)
            {
                case (int)CodeName:
                    _parser = new CodeNameParser();
                    break;
                case (int)CodeType:
                    _parser = new CodeTypeParser();
                    break;
                case (int)CodeNameType:
                    _parser = new CodeNameTypeParser();
                    break;
}

var results = Parse(stream).ToList(); //Parse returns IEnumerable<Product>
if (results.Any())
            {
                using (var streamWriter = File.CreateText(fileName))
                {
                    //writes the header line out
                    streamWriter.WriteLine("{0},{1}", header, name);

                    results.ForEach(p => { streamWriter.WriteLine(_parser .ConvertToOutputFormat(p)); });
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }

                Optional<string> newFileName = Optional.Of(SharpZipWrapper.ZipFile(fileName, RepositoryDirectory));
                //cleanup
                File.Delete(fileName);
                return newFileName;
            }
```

I don't want to go through the 5000 rows again to remove the duplicates but would like to check if the entry already exists before I add it to the csv file. I know that I can groupBy the required fields, but since I have 3 different outputs, I would have to write the same code 3 times for different keys that I need to group by.

```
results = results
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.ProductCode, p.Name, p.Type })
    .Select(g => new Product {
        ProductCode = g.Key.ProductCode,
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        Type = g.Key.Type,
        Price = g.Sum(p => p.Price)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear why you'd need to group by different things just because you're writing the values with a different format...

Comment: If I want to output all fields, I'd need to use the groupBy code above, but if I wanted to only output ProductCode and Name, this would change from `.GroupBy(p => new { p.ProductCode, p.Name, p.Type })` to `.GroupBy(p => new { p.ProductCode, p.Name })`.

Comment: This goes back to why you ever need to group by more than product code... You never made that clear.

Comment: I just added more example csv outputs that I would want. I don't understand how you could get all three types of these outputs by only Grouping by ProductCode and not the others?

Comment: My confusion is with "while reading" vs. describing these group bys after you've read 5000 records. If you want to keep tabs on counts while reading you will need additional data structures for each case to store it as you read each record.

Comment: The only way I can see is to precalculate sum for all types when you read data. For example you can create dictionary where key will code + name + type and value is Product where price is sum. Each time you create new product you will need to check the dictionary and if it exists already then to update the sum if not then to add new product to the dictionary. In the and it will produce 3 different (or amount you need) dictionaries that holds unrepeated rows with price summary.

Comment: How can product ABC be both trainers and heels? I can understand the different size, but surely the product code should uniquely identify the product...

Comment: The product code is for the category, i.e. Shoes.